# Bad Hash Function

Tags: java

I am confused about the hash function.
This is a good hash function

```
private int hash(K key) {
    return (key.hashCode() & 0x7fffffff) % M;
    }
```

How would I turn that into a very bad hash function,
would it be like this?

```
private int hash(K key) {
    return (key.hashCode() & 17) % M;
    }
```

Comment: The worst valid `hashCode() ` implentation is one that always returns the same constant value, e.g. `1`. This still fulfills the contract, but is obviously not very uniformly distributed.

Comment: so it could be any number like 1 or 17? ((key.hashCode() & 17))

Comment: Yes.  What makes it bad is that it reduces your bucket count to 1, thus turning your hash map into a linked list or an array, or what ever data structure is used to store information in the buckets.

Comment: See [Object.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) for the general contract (also see the one for `equals`, they are closely related).

Comment: Yes, thank you so much.

Comment: Basically, there are multiple ways to calculate reasonably well-distributed hash codes - most of them involve prime numbers. They differ in performance characteristics and details of the distribution they produce.